# Can I make an app on just 2 IOS devices with flutter on windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, flutter

I need to make an app only for 2 people on their iPhones. Is it possible to build an app with flutter on a windows OS and just install it on those 2 IOS devices? Because I saw that you need a Mac for publishing the app, but what about just installing it for separate devices?

Comment: You would still need a XCode on the Mac to make the project into a what's called an IPA.  The IPA is what you would be installing on the iOS devices

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. For build app for iOS and other Apple's platforms you need to have build tools that available only for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

No you need a MacOS to build app for iOS.

But you can use a tool called Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI) for that.

It's a tool that gives you access to MacOS build machines.

You can do everything from configuring Xcode, generating your IPA file and publishing your flutter app.